# .htaccess url rewrite path with exception

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rules in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^products$ /category/products [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products.*$ /category/products [R=301,L]
```

So far so good. My problem is that I have a page named: `/products-list` and it's getting rewritten by the second rule. I need to access that URL correctly

How can I add an exception to the rule for that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` right before the second rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products-list
RewriteRule ^products.*$ /category/products [R=301,L]
```

Since both rules have the same destination, you don't really need the first rule at all.